# Вввод цифр с плавающей запятой в текстовое поле и удаление запятой из поля

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы в поле вводились только цифры и цифры с плавающей запятой, при этом чтобы если в текстовое поле введен символ запятая без цифр он удалялся из текстового поля?

1. То есть ввели, - место запятой в поле должно стать пустым.
2. Запретить ввод одновременно сразу несколько запятых
3. При вводе цифр, например: `36,6` или `45` поле не очищается,
   остается без изменений

Comment: обычно хватает `<input type=number>`

Answer (score 4):

`/^\d+[.,]?\d*$/` — называется «Регулярное выражение».

**^** — начало строки

**\d** — англ. digit: цифра.

**+** — одно или много совпадений подряд.

**[...]** — несколько символов заключены в квадратные скобки, значит совпасть должен один из.

**?** — 0 или 1 раз (запрет на несколько точек/запятых подряд)

***** — ноль или много раз подряд. Т.е. после точки, цифры может и не быть. Числа вида '123.' всё еще проскакивают. Их всё равно надо дополнительно проверять перед отправкой, если это важно.

**$** — конец строки.

```js
setStrictNumberPattern();

function setStrictNumberPattern(){
  let inp = document.querySelectorAll('.js-strict-number-pattern');
  
  for( let i = 0; i < inp.length; i++ ){
    let lastVal = "";
    inp[i].addEventListener('input', function(){
      if( !this.value ) return (lastVal = "");
      // символ ! превращает false в true (и наоборот).
      // Если например стерли введенное и this.value оказался пустой строкой (false)
      // Условие сработает и return прервет функцию.
      
      if( (/^\d+[.,]?\d*$/).test( this.value ) ){
        lastVal = this.value = this.value.replace(/,/,".");
      } else {
        this.value = lastVal;
        // Если тест не прошел - возвращаем старое значение в инпут.
        
        //.. display error message.
      }
    });
  } 
}
```

```html
<input class="js-strict-number-pattern">
<input class="js-strict-number-pattern">
```

Comment: OPTIMUS PRIME а что значит / перед  ^ ?

Comment: @Leks в JS строки заключаются в "кавычки"... а это как-бы `/кавычки/` для регулярных выражений)